# Switching PlotLegends according to CheckboxBar selection

Tags: legending

In using `Manipulate` to illustrate selectively function dynamics I encountered the following difficulty with the `PlotLegends` option. There are three plots, which can be selected through the 'function' variable check boxes. They display separately or in combination. The `PlotLegends` option, however, only displays the legend labels in order, starting from the first one, regardless of which 'function' boxes are selected.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[function /. t -> tt], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Re[e^i(x-t)+e^i(x+t)]", "Re[e^i(x-t)]", "Im[e^i(x+t)]"}], 
{{function, {Re[Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]]}}, 
{Re[Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]] -> "Re[e^i(x-t)+e^i(x+t)]", 
Re[Exp[I (x - t)]] -> "Re[e^i(x-t)]", Im[Exp[I (x + t)]] -> "Im[e^i(x+t)]"}, 
CheckboxBar}, {{tt, 0, "t = 0 to 2Pi "}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Two illustrating images, showing mismatched function selection and plot legends, are included below.

[image: ![Mismatch 1]

[image: ![Mismatch 1]

I shall be grateful for any suggestions how to set the plot legends, so that they always correspond correctly to any combination of the function plot selections.
(There could be a trivial answer, but I have not succeeded in finding it.)

Comment: try using `PlotLegends -> function`?

Comment: Thank you kglr. I would not have worked out how exactly, but Daniel's answer was clear and helpful. Now I understand what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The order of the functions in the legend should remain constant as the selections change. Likewise, the color associated with each function should remain constant. To accomplish this, the [`CheckboxBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckboxBar.html) values should be indices.

```
funcs = {
   Re[Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]],
   Re[Exp[I (x - t)]],
   Im[Exp[I (x + t)]]};

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[funcs]];

Manipulate[
 function = Sort@function (* keeps legends in consistent order *);
 Plot[
  Evaluate[funcs[[function]] /. t -> tt],
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> colors[[function]] (* keeps colors consistent *),
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
  PlotLegends -> {funcs[[function]]}],
 {{function, {1, 2, 3}},
  Thread[Range[Length[funcs]] -> (TraditionalForm /@ funcs)],
  CheckboxBar},
 {{tt, 0, "t = 0 to 2Pi "}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Most impressive! My appreciation is much more than the +1 I am limited to. Thank you, Bob.

Answer (score 3):

You must specify as many labels as there are functions to plot:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[function /. t -> tt], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
  PlotLegends -> 
   Evaluate[
    function /. {Re[Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]] -> 
       "Re[e^i(x-t)+e^i(x+t)]", Re[Exp[I (x - t)]] -> "Re[e^i(x-t)]", 
      Im[Exp[I (x + t)]] -> "Im[e^i(x+t)]"}]]
 , {{function, {Re[Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]]}}, {Re[
     Exp[I (x - t)] + Exp[I (x + t)]] -> "Re[e^i(x-t)+e^i(x+t)]", 
   Re[Exp[I (x - t)]] -> "Re[e^i(x-t)]", 
   Im[Exp[I (x + t)]] -> "Im[e^i(x+t)]"}, 
  CheckboxBar}, {{tt, 0, "t = 0 to 2Pi "}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: enter+image+description+here]

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. I was not aware that PlotLegends can take such definitions. Works exactly as needed. Most helpful!